# Configuring HyperDB for WordPress Multi Site

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, partitioning, multisite

How to configure hyperdb in wordpress for multiserver databases?

I am having 100 blogs for the wordpress multisite. it will grow in the future may be it will become 200. Now i want to partition each blog's tables to seperate database or in group of blogs in one database.

So, my question is : Is it possible to use multiple databases concurrently for multisite for each blog's tables or group of blog's table?

I have configured hyperdb and have created 3 different blogs like site, site2, site3 here site is default blog for which database is called from my localhost, for site 2 and site 3 other databases are called from other server hosts. here issue is 2 out of 5 times it is giving error like ERROR ESTABLISHING DATABASE CONNECTION. So what should be done to overcome this issue.

In case there are other alternative solution to HyperDB, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to split up the blogs?

Comment: We want to setup multi-site environment where there will be more than 100 country specific sites. We want to separate database table and deploy them in separate databases near to specific regions using Amazon AWS cloud to avoid latency issues. That's the reason we will need to use HyberDB for database partitioning.

Comment: I thought WP used one _database_ per _user_.